# AskUbuntu and Brainstorm

Tags: discussion

AskUbuntu has done a good job that the people ask them solves the makeshift. Ubuntu BrainStorm, had made ​​a great role temple ahy not many comments yet, apart from this outdated the web. Building a merger between the two pages would be the best solution. Since the ideas are being generated on both a web as in the other can lead developers to new fields.

Comment: http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/28071

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can barely understand your question but I take it you're asking if Ask Ubuntu and Brainstorm can be merged (I've had people ask me in the past and it seems to be what you are asking).

The answer to that question is, not really; the sites are totally different and have different purposes. This is a question and answer site (see [the FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq)). Brainstorm is a place for people to submit ideas about Ubuntu and then people vote on them.

The one common thing that people might confuse is that both sites have voting, but other than that, the sites are totally different, even though from a quick glance they might look similar.

Comment: Sorry for my english. I say this because I see several proposals in ArkUbuntu,  but this forgotten brainstorm ubuntu. Without even if there are lots of different objectives like.

Comment: Do you have any links to proposals? We usually close those pretty quickly.