# Is it ok to mention a Brainstorm proposal in Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, scope

This may be off-topic even for Meta, but I'd like some clarification before I do something stupid.

I've just created a Brainstorm proposal. Is it ok to mention it as part of a useful answer within Ask Ubuntu?

For example, there's this question: [Thunderbird date format?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168264/thunderbird-date-format)

Could I go answer it and explain how to do the whole thing, step by step, and only then add a link to my Brainstorm idea, that deals with exactly that issue?

Jorge's answer here in Meta would seem to indicate otherwise http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1478/askubuntu-and-brainstorm but I'd like for us to establish official policy.

The idea is this one, if that's relevant: http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/30055/

Answer (score 4):

**Merging** Ask Ubuntu and Brainstorm is not an option, we're two different things.

However, referring to a Brainstorm proposal in a Ask Ubuntu **answer** is ok with me, just as we talk about [how if it weren't for this bug, this would work.](https://askubuntu.com/a/97248/6005)

Comment: No, no. Merging is not something I support, I just used that question to point to Jorge's answer. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not speaking as official advice, but I don't see a problem. I often post links to bug reports, and this is similarly useful. I would, however, mention to upvote suggestions that you like:

> While this is not implemented, and there is no program you can use to
>   so this, there is a brainstorm proposal
>   [here](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/30055/). I recommend that if you
>   want this to be implemented, that you upvote solutions you like.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.